# Annote field causing biblatex error

Tags: biblatex, errors

I have a bibliography entry that causes an error.

```
@incollection{Ursoiu2013Economic-effici,
    Annote = {% 2015-06-17

The article focuses on the concept of "good administration", reforms around this topic, its relation to legality and efficiency and whether the legal operationalization of good administration on the European level provides an external normative framework for the exercise of discretion of public agencies and other organs.

The first part of the article (section 3) focuses on the tension between legitimacy and efficiency in the development of "administrative systems"

The second part (section 4) discusses the legal operationalizartion of a "principle of good administration" on the European level.

---

Efficiency has been the prevailing paradigm for "structural adjustment reforms" – changes in the structure of administration through NPM. An "ethos of efficiency" promoted by the IMF, World Bank and Council of Europe.

},
    Author = {Naomi Reniutz Ursoiu},
    Booktitle = {Administrative law beyond the state : Nordic perspectives},
    Date-Added = {2015-06-17 12:53:11 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-08-12 09:02:50 +0000},
    Editor = {Anna-Sara Lind and Jane Reichel},
    Publisher = {Martinus Nijhoff Publishers},
    Read = {1},
    Title = {Economic efficiency and legality as criteria for the development of good administration in a globalized order},
    Year = {2013}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,language=swedish,autocite=footnote,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/Users/xjtorm/Dropbox/referenser.bib}
\title{Test} 
\author{Tormod Otter Johansen}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\autocite[]{Ursoiu2013Economic-effici}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Running this causes the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\field {booktitle}{Administrative law beyond the state : Nordic pers\ETC.
./manuskript-avhandling.tex:83: File ended while scanning use of \field.
```

This solves itself if the `annote` field is left out of the bibtex entry. But is this the only way to solve it? Do I use the annote field incorrectly?

Comment: the problem is the comment, i.e., `%` inside `annote`.  If you remove it it works properly.  The `biblatex/bibtex` way would be to create a new field `myannotationdate` to store such information. The field will be ingnored by `biber` or `bibtex`.

Comment: The date comment seems hardly necessary seeing that you have `Date-Added` and `Date-Modified` already (which are both ignored by BibTeX/Biber). Of course you can use Biber to zap the `annote` field before it becomes toxic in the `.bbl` file. (With `\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=annote,null]
    }
  }
}`)

Comment: Aha, the date is just a remainder from when I wrote the annotation. But does this mean I use the field correctly? It can contain any text?

Comment: Fields may contain a lot of stuff if you don't want them typeset. If you want them to be printed in the document you might face certain restrictions. The few things you need to take care of is that what you write in the field actual allows a proper processing of the `.bib` file. Comments within fields can cause troubles with Biber (and in fewer cases also with BibTeX). So, technically you are almost using the field right.

Comment: The question is whether it is good usage. If you just want to write down some commentary which you don't intend to ever end up in a typeset document, you might as well use a field that is automatically ignored by Biber/BibTeX ans Guido points out, because then you might fill the field with almost anything you like.

Comment: @moewe, thank you. That makes it all clear. Should you or @guido post an answer so I can mark it as accepted? When writing the question I thought about writing an answer myself (that removing the `annote` field would be enough) but it didn’t seem like I had actually solved something.

Comment: @Guido Since you have solved the mystery, do you want to write up an answer. (Maybe also hinting at what I wrote in the comments.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the comment, i.e. `%`, in the `annote` field.

`biber` takes the argument of the field and produce a `.bbl` where the lines in the argument are joined in a single line. Thus we have something looking like

```
...
\field{annotation}{% ...} 
\field{title}{title}
```

This means that LaTeX does not see the closing bracket `}` of  the value of annotation.

The situation is a bit different when the backend is `bibtex`. In this case the generate `.bbl` file contains

```
...
\field{annotation}{% 
  %...
  ...%
} 
\field{title}{title}
```

`bibtex` joins the lines in the bibtex field, but then it splits them at a fixed width.

The `%` in the line after the line with `\field{annotation}{%` is the comment in the bibtex field.  So in this case there will be no error, but  the output will not be correct.

So as @moewe said, it is fine to have comments in bibtex fields as long as the fields are ignore by the bibliography processor and not use to be typeset.

In some fields contains `%` a solution is to use `sourcemap`, to nullify the value, i.e.,

```
\DeclareSourcemap{ \maps{ \map{ \step[fieldset=annote,null] } } }
```

The source map operates on the bibtex records before it is written to the `.bbl` file.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you can mention that sourcemapping a field to `null` using BIber is fine because it will not be output to the `.bbl` then.